# HTML баг с ссылкой на картинку

Tags: html

Когда я вставляю фотку в мое меню, то голубая рамка на скрине1 - это ее границы.
Когда я элемент `img` вставляю в элемент `a`, то второй элемент добавляет ещё свою рамку (скрин2), по которой тоже можно переходить на другую страницу, и у меня по этим двум рамкам можно переходить, выглядит некрасиво, возможно ли как-нибудь убрать другую рамки от элемента `a`, или уменьшить и переместить в первую, или что-нибудь ещё сделать с ней, чтобы по ней не перекидывало на мою другую страницу?

[image: Снимок с экрана №1]
[image: Снимок с экрана №2]

Comment: У вас вёрстка не корректная. В `ul` нельзя помещать ничего кроме `li`. Также ссылка у вас строчная, а картинка строчно-блочная. Сделайте обе строчно-блочные и тогда не будет лишних кусочков.

Comment: Что указывает на строчный и блочный елемент?

Comment: У вас на скрине картинка inline-block. А ссылка строчная по умолчанию. Не может строчный элемент вмещать блочный нормально, поэтому обычно так и соскакивает вниз.

Comment: Я убирал inline block и ничего не меняется, а если 'a' и 'img' убираю из 'ul' то header становится шире, а мне нужно что бы все в одной строчке было

Comment: А вы пробовали не убирать, а сделать как я говорил?

Comment: То есть добавить display:inline-block к елементу 'a'?

Comment: Да, чтобы он перестал быть строчным

Comment: Сделал, ничего не изменилось, так же есть лишний кусочек

Comment: Покажите ссылку на реальный пример или тут код вставьте чтобы не гадать

Comment: <ul class="content">
                            <a  href="index.html" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; line-height:1px; padding-left: 25px;" > 
                                <img style="display:inline-block;" src="logo3.png" width="97" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                            <li><a href="informacja.html">Informacja</a></li>
                            <li><a href="strony.html">Moje strony</a></li>
                            <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                        </ul>

Comment: Сейчас этот кусочек исчез, но весь padding-left: 25px, то есть 25 пикселей до края начала страницы тоже ссылка

Comment: Ну сделайте вместо паддинга маргин тогда.

Comment: Супер! Теперь все как и хотел! Спасибо!

Comment: Хоть и элементы 'a' и 'img' я оставил в списке 'ul'

Comment: Браузер за вас делает какое-то исправление, так делать не стоит

Comment: Но все же когда я эту картинку пишу перед списком, то структура ломается

Comment: А если я например еще хочу что бы картинка при наведении менялась то пишу 
a.menulogo:hover {
    background: url(logo3.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: 97px;
}
Но она появляется не на том же месте как изначальная картинка а чуть ниже, то что сделать в таком случае?

Comment: Формат данного ресурса не предполагает общение как на форуме. Найдите форум какой-то или более свободный в этом плане сайт или учителя.